# How to send JSON data from Activity to Fragment?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to fetch data from JSON and send a part of data to all Fragments.
Here is my code:

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager,ArrayList<Product> productname,int p) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
 }
        String price = productname.get(1).getPrice();
        args.putString("key", price);
        TheFragment tf1 = new TheFragment();
        TheFragment tf2 = new TheFragment();
        TheFragment tf3 = new TheFragment();
        TheFragment tf4 = new TheFragment();
        adapter.addFragment(tf1 , "ONE");
        tf1.setArguments(args);
        adapter.addFragment(tf2 , "Two");
        tf2.setArguments(args);
        adapter.addFragment(tf3 , "Three");
        tf3.setArguments(args);
        adapter.addFragment(tf4 , "Four");
        tf4.setArguments(args); 

 //3      adapter.addFragment(new TheFragment(), "TWO"); // Can I send data by coding this way?
 //3     adapter.addFragment(new TheFragment(), "THREE");
 //3       adapter.addFragment(new TheFragment(),"THE 4");
       viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Before this I have retrieved JSON value in a array list and  `n=jsonArray.length();`.

```
setupViewPager(viewPager,arrayList,n);
```

The JSON file contains name, price and image. I want to display prices in my fragments.

```
public class TheFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tv;
    public TheFragment() {

    }
    String value = getArguments().getString("key");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*    if(value!=null){
            tv.setText(value);
        } */

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_this, container, false);
        tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.thePrice);
        tv.setText(value);
        return view;
    }
}
```

The code is not showing any error but app is not running. What are the mistakes I am doing and possible solutions available? Thanks.

Comment: is your fragment already open when you are sending json to them.

Comment: My Fragments open when I did not send anything but as I am trying to send data and want to set text in fragment layout's textview it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Change this lines of code in your fragment-

```
   public class TheFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tv;
    public TheFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_this, container, false);
    }

   @Override
   public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
       tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.thePrice);
   }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String price = getArguments().getString("key");
        tv.setText(price);
    }
}
```

Hope will work well.

Comment: how it will work ? Fragment is already on  top  so now you will not get value inside onActivityCreated()

Comment: @jiteshmohite I have run the code and it works because viewPager.setAdapter(adapter) is called after setting arguments. And all the datas are preloaded. So when adapter will attach the fragment it will definitely go thorough onActivityCreated().

Comment: @Saket Pleasure is mine. :) If it helps you, then please try to accept the answer.

Comment: I am new here and tried to accept but it is asking 15 + reputation. I am sorry but I don't even know much about the reputation that it is asking about.

Comment: Its okey. :D I am just kidding. I am glad that it helps you. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Saket: there should be a tick mark below the down arrow of the answer. click that tick mark to accept the answer. there is no reputation restriction to do that action.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use newInstance method in fragment as below.

```
public static Fragment newInstance(ArrayList<Product> jsonData) {

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putStringArrayList("Key","jsonDatainArray");
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
}
```

And initialize fragment as below

```
 TheFragment theFragment= TheFragment.newInstance("arrayListHere");
```

Use `getArguments()` method to get the arrayList in `onCreateView` or `onCreate` in Fragment.

Comment: you can put the data as json string too.